# If I use MediaPlayer's setWakeMode method, is it released automatically and if so, when?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Android's MediaPlayer class has a nifty method that lets you set a wakelock:

```
mPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
```

My question is: when is this wakelock released? Does it happen automatically when I call

```
mPlayer.release();
```

or am I missing something?

Here's the official docs for the method: [MediaPlayer.setWakeMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setWakeMode(android.content.Context,%20int))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is: when is this wakelock released? Does it happen
>   automatically when I call
>
> mPlayer.release();

Yes it is. Checking their source, [MediaPlayer.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b267554/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java). `release()` calls `stayAwake()` that tells whether to hold/release a wakelock.

```
private void stayAwake(boolean awake) {
    if (mWakeLock != null) {
        if (awake && !mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            mWakeLock.acquire();
        } else if (!awake && mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
            mWakeLock.release();
        }
    }
    mStayAwake = awake;
    updateSurfaceScreenOn();
}

public void release() {
    stayAwake(false);
    updateSurfaceScreenOn();
    mOnPreparedListener = null;
    mOnBufferingUpdateListener = null;
    mOnCompletionListener = null;
    mOnSeekCompleteListener = null;
    mOnErrorListener = null;
    mOnInfoListener = null;
    mOnVideoSizeChangedListener = null;
    mOnTimedTextListener = null;
    if (mTimeProvider != null) {
        mTimeProvider.close();
        mTimeProvider = null;
    }
    mOnSubtitleDataListener = null;
    _release();
}

private native void _release();
```